# Как на андроид сохранить png картинки в память телефона?

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask

Всем добрый день!
У меня возник такой вопрос:
имеется серия ссылок в массиве, которые необходимо в фоновом процессе загрузить на память телефона(в мой кэш), при этом хотелось бы устанавливать параметры компрессии изображения.
Буду рад любой помощи!
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: А что такое *мой кэш*? Это стандартный кэш или ваш кастомный кэш?

Comment: Стандартный: com.my_pack.my_app и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
Bitmap bitmap;  // ссылка на существующий битмап
Context context; //ссылка на контекст приложения

//открываем файл в приватном каталоге нашей аппы
OutputStream stream = context.openFileOutput("test.png", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);// пишем битмап на PNG с качеством 70%
stream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

- [How do I transfer an image from its URL to the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296850/how-do-i-transfer-an-image-from-its-url-to-the-sd-card)
- [Android Tutorial+Free Source Code Download](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/download-store-and-read-images-from.html)
- [How can I save an image from a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388666/how-can-i-save-an-image-from-a-url)

Ну и соответственно, если у вас массив ссылок, то все вышеуказанные действия нужно проделать в цикле.
Это стандартная задача, которая гуглится за 2 минуты.

Comment: @Andreich это все понятно, но суть вопроса как сохранить изображение на память телефона(в кеш) при этом изменяя размеры изображения.

Comment: так а что вам мешает сначала изменить размер bitmap, а потом его сохранить

Comment: Попробовал все три Ваших примера и еще несколько других! Ни один из них коректно не работает!
Мне просто элементарно нужно сохранить каринку по сслыке(http://ofs.ft-ru.ru/storage/catalogs/664e5b1b1d8a165606df981e2ac3a94e.png) на память телефона в папку приложения!